# Shows 100%, but file not uploaded

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have used file input plugin to upload files.

```
<input id="input-id" type="file" accept=".mp3, .mp4" name="file" class="form-control"><br>
<input type="hidden" id="getfilename" name="uploadedfile" value="">
```

And this jquery:

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({
        maxFileSize: 264000,
        uploadUrl: "{{url('/rate/uploadfile')}}", 
        uploadAsync: true,
        uploadExtraData:{'_token':$("#csrf_token").val()},
        allowedFileExtensions: ['mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'flv'],
        maxFileCount: 1,
        showUpload: true,
        dropZoneEnabled: false,

});
```

And the controller:

```
public function uploadfile()
{   
    $target_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\larafirst\public\newuploads';
    $tmpname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $target_file= $target_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.basename($newfilename);
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $target_file)){
        echo json_encode($newfilename);die;
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(false);die;
    }
}
```

It shows the green tick mark and 100%  while uploading, but it is never uploaded. else statement is always executed. it displays `false` in uploadfile.

Comment: any error in console firebug ?

Comment: any errors in the php?

Comment: how large is the file, are you exceeding the upload_max_size php setting?  anything in the php error log?

Comment: have you written enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form ?

Comment: can you show the error? as what others above me suggest, can you check your php config for upload size?